# Sprintf and float values on serial port IAR

Tags: c, floating-point

I've the following snippet of code which I'm compiling on my IAR workbench.

```
// global declaration
float fval = 3.14f;
uint8_t uartTxBuffer [100];

void function(void)
{
  memset(uartTxBuffer,'\0',sizeof(uartTxBuffer);
  sprintf(uartTxBuffer,"\n\r Value is %f",fval);
  UartWrite(uart, uartTxBuffer,strlen(uartTxBuffer));
}
```

The output is 
`Value is %f     // and not 3.14`
Can someone explain me what is the issue in my code?
Is it the Uartwrite function or am I making some mistake in using the C language?
I've tried the same code using printf on Keil MDK and it outputs the correct value on the serial terminal. So is this an IDE issue?
Can someone guide me here?

Comment: What hapens if you use ```%.2f```?

Comment: It would seem you have a version of the standard library, which does not support floating point. There's probably some option somewhere to enable it (if you build it along with your app), or a version which has support enabled (if you use existing library file). Keil may have different defaults.

Comment: @hyde is correct. IAR has (ARM version at least) a configurable level for printf support. Check the library options in your project options first.

Comment: @Melon Same result as that of "%f".

Comment: @hyde Yeah, I'll probably have to find that option. I'll check if such option is available in IAR.

Comment: @hyde I checked the options in IAR. It had 2 options under Floating-point semantics -- Strict conformance and Relaxed (smaller and/ or faster). I tried both the options but it still outputs `%f` for both `%.2f` and `%f`

Comment: @NISHITKHARA I don't think that option is related to this issue. That's basically optimization option for which kind of assembly code the compiler generates for floating point operations. Your issue is with the standard library version in use, and the printf implementation in there.

Comment: So where in IAR can I find this option related to the way in which printf is implemented? Can you tell me?

Comment: Sorry, no. It's something which is decided when the C standard library is built (or when a particular library file is chosen when your project is built). I'd look for some kind of config.h, maybe. But, simplest solution might be to google for "c float to string implementation", and just have your own function for the purpose.

Comment: I already made my own function and implemented it in my project but I was curious about finding the cause of this behavior and also it's solution.

Answer (score 0):

After a brief research this came up

https://www.iar.com/support/tech-notes/general/problems-with-printf-floating-point-f-on-arm/

The problem seems to be the byte alignment of the Stack Pointer. 
Set a breakpoint on the sprintf() call and check the value of the stack pointer in the debugger.

Most of the answers I found are related to FreeRTOS ( which I don't know if you are using it):

[sprintf breaking under new FreeRTOS](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/January_2013/freertos_sprintf_breaking_under_new_FreeRTOS_6647463.html)

[sprintf %f corrupts stack](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/December_2016/freertos_sprintf_f_corrupts_stack_8fbac97dj.html)

[sprintf in FreeRTOS](https://www.freertos.org/FreeRTOS_Support_Forum_Archive/November_2015/freertos_sprintf_in_FreeRTOS_76ff6992j.html)

A common solution is to resort to

> a third party library called printf-stdarg.c that provides a tiny print/sprintf/printf implementation for use in cases where the libraries that come with the compiler are just too big for small embedded use

I hope this might help

Comment: That first link doesn't work (probably requires being logged in). However, this issue seems to be different, because `%f` is just printed out, which means it's just not supported. If your answer would apply here, I think printout would be different (even correct), but there'd be crash or other stack corruption symptom. Or did I misunderstand something?

Comment: @hyde Yes. It prints %f. Is this something to do with a memory leak problem? I've found some questions which discusses a memory leak problem when we use the sprintf method for float values. Probably the stack pointer change and the memory leak are related?